Is there a way to render someone braindead while leaving the organs and body fully intact?
In my story, the antagonist is an evil empire (Chromeia) that massacres civilians as reprisals and enslaves prisoners of war. They're similar to the Roman Empire in many ways, only with modern technology.
One of the largest industries in Chromeia is blood/organ exports. In order to do this, Chromeians force slaves to reproduce. The Chromeians then take that baby, render it braindead while leaving the physical body (excluding brain) mostly unharmed, and then store it. The baby corpse will be hanged up in a room full of other braindead babies. All of the corpses will be fed intravenously so they can still grow, generate new cells, and maintain organs. The braindead corpses will regularly have their blood,plasma, platelets etc. extracted to meet market demands. Organs are also regularly harvested from the corpses. When a corpse has ran out of organs or has just outlived its usefulness, they are thrown en masse into a crematorium.
Is there a process to make a person (especially a newborn) braindead without harming other parts of their body? Will this process harm the quality of the exports in anyway compared to standard donations?

Yes. Cheapest way to do that is called >! youtube. All the other options require high technology with professional care. It the USA, a day in the intensive care of a hospital is between $2000-$6000/day, while people can survive on about $1000/month without major risk of an insurgency.

That seems very wasteful. Why not let them grow up and let them do forced labour, and then kill a grownup whenever you want to sell a liver and a few liters of blood? Saves you all the costly equipment that would be required to let a braindead baby physically mature, plus you get a workforce as well.

@EikePierstorff But you also get people with autonomy, who can do nasty things like damage the goods, or attempt a prison break.

@wizzwizz4 if you can turn babies to EEG flatliners, you can as easily turn them to moronic junkies. No more autonomous than braindead and much, much easier to make behave: no treadmill exercice, no dope! No shower between treadmill and lunch, no dope, sorry!

Actually give them unlimited access to the internet and watch their mental facilities waste away. They will still be alive but unable to have any original thoughts instead only able to repeat that latest meme they saw. There are undesirable effects, by being immobile for large amounts of time their general health will get progressively worse and they will die prematurely.

+1. The ICU prices (to some degree) reflect the level of care needed to keep a body functioning when the brain does not work. Mechanical ventilation is really just the tip of an iceberg - and even with that level of care infections are common and long-term survival rates are not great.

Crossreference Frank Herbert's Axolotl Tanks (Dune) and reproductive stumps (Hellstrom's Hive)

I'm pretty sure one of Robert Heinlein's novels (maybe The Number of the Beast) included anencephalic clones kept as a source for compatible "spare parts".

There is a form of medical life support for organ donors, that is they are physically dying (such as in a car accident), and they receive therapies (such as dialysis to preserve kidney from AKI). Problem is that experience is short term, but theoretically it could go indefinitely, and literally taking a healthy person and beating them unconscious periodically is not beyond the reason of macabre plotline.

go watch the movie "the island". they take considerable care to create healthy organ donors. your braindead babies wouldn't produce any organs i'd want in my body.

The efficient economic way is imprisonment for 'life' work them hard (no not that hard) until their judicial appeal process completed - ages between 18 to 25 - and then their (no not capital punishment, rather their organ punishment) day of delivery is executed and some large nameless firm drone delivers them to the ordering clinics - the most usually purchased being prime grade A.

Referring to "organs and body" implies that there is "organs or body".  That makes no sense.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6grTFSOUznU&t=141s

Ever heard the phrase "running like a chicken with its head cut off"? Well, the origin of the phrase is that when the butcher would cut the head off the chicken, he would slightly miss and perform a kind of craniectomy. In that case, the brain stem is in-tact. Here's a horrific story of a man who kept such a chicken alive for a year and a half as a kind of freakshow attraction: https://www.britannica.com/story/how-mike-the-chicken-survived-without-a-head
While the brain regulates major physical functions, the essential part, the brain stem, is physically located at the top of the neck and controls breathing and heartbeat. Data from humans suggest our brain is much the same. Of course, there's subtleties, but there's no reason not to expect a cruel and barbaric practice could gain experience in this area, and get it down to an art. So, ya know, cut out most of the brain but preserve the brain stem and a person could be kept alive for quite a while.

Rationalize this with a perfected method of medically induced coma

An induced coma – also known as a medically induced coma (MIC), barbiturate-induced coma, or drug-induced coma – is a temporary coma (a deep state of unconsciousness) brought on by a controlled dose of an anesthetic drug, often a barbiturate such as pentobarbital or thiopental. Other intravenous anesthetic drugs such as midazolam or propofol may be used.
Drug-induced comas are used to protect the brain during major neurosurgery, as a last line of treatment in certain cases of status epilepticus that have not responded to other treatments, and in refractory intracranial hypertension following traumatic brain injury. Source

There are problems with "brain dead." Dead is dead. You can hook the body up to a machine, but you can't keep it going forever (at least we don't know how to do that today), so it's really undesirable to actually "kill" the person. You just want the person to go away. This can be done with a medically induced coma, which leaves the brain's ability to control the body inherently in place, but the personality is out of the way and not developing.
However, there are problems even with this:

Induced coma usually results in significant systemic adverse effects. The patient is likely to completely lose respiratory drive and require mechanical ventilation; gut motility is reduced; hypotension can complicate efforts to maintain cerebral perfusion pressure and often requires the use of vasopressor drugs. Hypokalemia often results. The completely immobile patient is at increased risk of bed sores as well as infection from catheters. (Ibid.)

No matter how perfectly you remove the cognitive brain function, you're stuck with some nasty side effects that could compromise your final story. Brain dead or comatose people don't move.

Within a week, your problems only get worse. You see, normally, your muscles and bones help support your weight under gravity. But now that you're lying down, they're out of a job. And as the saying goes, if you don't use 'em, you lose 'em. For every week in bed, you lose about 1% of your bone density, making your bones more brittle and easy to fracture. (Source)

Go read that entire article, that quote only describes one problem. Granted, the article is about staying permanently in bed and you might hang your dead babies up... but the truth comes out in that statement, "if you don't use 'em, you lose 'em." You might try to use something like electrical stimulation, and it would work... to a degree..., but what you won't have twenty years later are particularly healthy organs. In fact, the whole body would be pretty substandard because, in a nutshell, it never really gets used. Bodies need to do things to develop healthy organs.
So, though this sounds devastatingly ruthless and may offend some readers (for which I'm very sorry!), what you really want to induce isn't a state of brain dead, you want to induce a severe mental retardation
I assume you're chasing this idea for its shock value. But this usually means there's some intrepid adventurers who open the proverbial door to discover (gasp!) a room full of dead people hanging or stacked there waiting to be harvested for organs so the ruling elite or wealthy can continue to live happy lives. Frankly, this would have been a better premise than what was used for the movie The Island, but I digress.
Personally, I think a greater shock value (and a more believable process that experiences fewer problems) is, at birth, to introduce severe mental retardation.

Severe Mental Retardation is defined by the presence of significantly subaverage general intellectual functioning as well as significant limitations in adaptive functioning (adaptive behavior) present prior to the age of 18 years. Individuals with a diagnosis of severe mental retardation generally obtain IQ scores within the range of 20–25 to 35–40.

The goal is to have a happy child that jumps and plays and runs around and does healthy things, but is nevertheless one that is intrinsically perceived (and is) a burden on society as the individual will never be a significant contributor (other than as a passive organ donor), but rather always a dependent.
If you're not wiggling around in your chair right now trying to figure out how to chastise me for even suggesting this... you're one cold-hearted <redacted>.
The government doesn't just warehouse the bodies, there's an entire welfare system set up with a large bureaucracy to manage the growth and health of the children. I'm thinking classic Russian closed cities where the children (and their harvesting) are kept out of the public's eye.
Maybe it's just me, but I think this is a deeper, darker, more evil secret than a room full of dead bodies. A brain dead child had something evil done to them only once. These kids experience evil in the form of smiling healthcare workers day after day after day with no conception that a day will come when they're finally killed.
I love the idea... how could it be rationalized?

Anytime something interferes with normal brain development, intellectual disability can result. However, a specific cause for intellectual disability can only be pinpointed about a third of the time.
The most common causes of intellectual disability are:

Genetic conditions. These include things like Down syndrome and fragile X syndrome.
Problems during pregnancy. Things that can interfere with fetal brain development include alcohol or drug use, malnutrition, certain infections, or preeclampsia.
Problems during childbirth. Intellectual disability may result if a baby is deprived of oxygen during childbirth or is born extremely premature.
Illness or injury. Infections like meningitis, whooping cough, or the measles can lead to intellectual disability. Severe head injury, near-drowning, extreme malnutrition, infections in the brain, exposure to toxic substances such as lead, and severe neglect or abuse can also cause it.
None of the above. In two-thirds of all children who have intellectual disabilities, the cause is unknown. (Source)


I'm a fan of not trying to explain everything. Honestly, authors open themselves to more criticism by trying to realistically explain everything than they ever would if they left some of the details to the imagination. In other words, as useful as those bullets might be, it's the last one that's the most useful. Generally speaking, humanity has no honking clue how severe mental retardation occurs.
But your government does.
Your government knows...

Where in the brain damage influence must be brought to bear to completely inhibit cognitive development.

The chemical that permanently disrupts synaptic growth. Let's call it Oclordex (name generated via Drug-O-Matic).

The medical technology and/or procedure to deliver the chemical such that the personality is affected, but not the brain's ability to control the body.


Do you remember the scene from Will Smith's I, Robot when Susan Calvin injects a robot's positronic brain with nanites, which flow through the brain, destroying it? Yeah. Now imagine cutting open a baby's head and carefully inserting needles into the folds of his/her brain to gently spray specific areas with Oclordex. (I'd tell you to do this in the Frontal Lobe, but that's become such a scifi trope....) Said procedure performed by either a pure sociopath or a true believer (go watch the movie Serenity).
My point is, it's not specifically important how the government achieves this goal. It's important to know the nature of the people who would order it and do it. Shock doesn't come from (as an example) knowing the chemical composition of Oclordex. Shock comes from compelling the reader to think to themselves, "there's a bit of that darkness in me...."

Huxley's Brave New World built an entire caste system around similar ideas. I don't recall any mention of organ transplantation, but probably any of the lower castes would have been fair game for a sufficiently important Alpha or Beta, and the Epsilons might not have been able to understand the implications.

I suggest you listen to "Jefferson 37", which can be found here: https://archive.org/details/ProjectRaphaelBBCr4
It's the 3rd series in the list.

Want some extra darkness with your darkness? Make the process to make a baby into a "harvest baby" an option for low-cast citizens, for which they get paid. People would make babies to "sell" as organ harvesting bodies, just to get the money to survive... The shock factor of "bodies for harvesting organs" is now doubled with the shock factor of "making children to make money".

While reading your horrifying ideas, lobotomy crept up in my mind as a possible method. You deliberately damage a part of the brain which leaves the person in an almost vegetative state. No emotions, no desires, jst pure obedience.

Have you ever read Never let me go by Kazuo Ishiguro, or seen the film? It's like The Island, but far more depressing because the backdrop is the whole of society deciding that clones weren't people and hence could be used as just bags of organs to be taken at will. The Island relied on the outside world not knowing. Never let me go assumes the whole world knows and just goes along with it for the selfish benefits they get.

Wouldn't there be a significant risk that the mentally retarded child runs head first into a wall or drinks bleach or does something else to damage those valuable organs? You would need people to constantly keep watch on these children. This wouldn't be a low-maintenance solution.

@GiantSpaceHamster The OP didn't specify low-maintenance, but I concluded the need for high quality. Thus, cost is second to quality and the entire bureaucracy I mention in my answer becomes rationalized. Besides, when was the last time you saw a government do anything efficiently? :-)

@Graham I thought about that, but concluded the need for secrecy. I certainly see your point as it would be one very dysfunctional society that would permit such atrocity. There are different kinds of shock that can be had here: the depravity of society, the dysfunction of the government, the calloused disregard for human beings, and many more. It's just a question of what combination one wants to focus on.

Isn't the thing your looking for just a lobotomy? People have already done that

@DonQuiKong No. Most people misunderstand what a lobotomy is. Many lobotomy patients go on to live perfectly normal lives. A part of the problem is that humanity is only just beginning to understand the brain. The other part of the problem is that Hollywood presents lobotomies as rendering people stupid or vegetable-like. Worse, it's a trope and that's boring. My answer provides the OP something much closer to what he/she was expecting.

Why not right away farming of feral children? If kept away from education long enough, they stop being able to learn.

@Rafael That would work! But it's nowhere near as evil, which is the assumption I made about the OP's question (since he wanted dead bodies to begin with).

A surgical partial severing of the C4 vertebra
From here
Now - this does not result in Brain Death... but it does render the individual immobile and alive - you have already indicated that they are an Evil Empire - so what is more evil than having a bunch of people unable to move or do anything, but still remain fully conscious whilst they are being harvested for their organs.
This is all sorts of body-horror fun.

A few problems with this.
Parts of the brain regulate a number of the bodies functions, keeping the body alive without these parts of the brain would be difficult and costly, leave the brain stem intact.
In minors you would need to prevent harm to any of the areas of the brain that are responsible for producing hormones that lead to development into an adult.
The major problem is that human bodies need to have regular exercise to be in optimal health.  Expect massive muscle atrophy if they just sit in a warehouse.  Specifically the heart will be in bad shape, but expect other medical issues.
Disturbingly there are precedents for things like this, lobotomies exist... and they were done on children.  Howard Dully was lobotomized when he was 12 years old in 1960, he lived to adulthood and is still alive.  He even got a degree in computer information systems.

"Howard Dully...". G-d that's an awful story.

A braindead person will often die a true death in short time. Braindead people usually die within hours to days, and even to be kept "alive" they need mechanical ventilation, because a dead brain will not cause the lungs to move.
A more productive way would be to put people in a drug induced coma, which is an actual medical procedure. This greatly reduces the need for mechanical ventilation, keeps the body fresher, and is less likely to be botched.
I don't know about doing it to babies, though. I assume it would mess up their development, so the organs would be useless, or less efficient in a way. If you are going the slave route, why not just harvest the adults?

Probably because it's easier to convince the rest of the populace that "It's okay because [Justification] means they aren't people". Easy to believe when they reap the benefits and bear none of the cost. That changes really quickly when they are the ones being harvested for organs.

'Brain Dead' can be a relative term.  It can mean that substantial parts of the brain are literally dead or disconnected, or it can mean that someone appears not to think.  Take the following quote from Star Wars Episode I:

Are you brain dead?  I'm not going in there with two jedi!  Send a droid.

So, Chromeia wants people to harvest for organs and fluids.  As previous answers have said, having inert bodies in storage is expensive, wasteful and counter-productive.
However there is a solution based on reality, even if I can't (and don't really want to) put a specific name to it: administer a drug to the pregnant slave women that results in their children being born with severe mental retardation.  They can still do everything a normal person can do, but they just never develop mentally beyond the cognitive abilities of a three-year-old... perhaps a three-year-old with adult hormones.
So, Chromeia ends up with docile, stupid, easily controlled slaves who can be harvested, and who can keep themselves fit and fed.
As a bonus, if necessary, these slaves can be used to bear perfectly normal children... or more retarded slaves.

+1. But drugs are risky. Put an iron band on the head of a baby to prevent cranial growth and you get people who grow with induced microcephaly, as they do in Pakistan (google for "rat children").

Yes, drugs are risky... but these are slaves.  To the Chromeians, if a few babies are stillborn or have more serious deficits than just being retarded... meh.... they can be disposed of easily enough.

"easily controlled" -- I know what you mean, but to pick a nit: 3-year-olds are notoriously difficult to control.

You could do something like "pithing" a laboratory animal. However, a body that doesn't get up and move around enough is not going to be healthy and the parts are going to be sub-standard in quality, leading to unnecessarily low export earnings.
Perhaps the brain could be largely or entirely surgically removed and replaced by a small computer that would drive the body to keep itself alive (if the hindbrain is removed) and to walk around, work out and perhaps even perform useful functions that either don't require intelligence or where intelligence is a disadvantage, to compensate for the nutrients consumed.
We already have prostheses that are controlled by myoelectric human nerve signals, so it would simply be an expansion of that concept.
